# rectangles on Grace plots

Tags: plot, rectangles, xmgrace

I have been using Grace (xmgrace) plotting for many years. I recently had an important idea for my work, and it involves rectangles on my plots. Grace supports rectangles (called "boxes"), but when I use a filled "box" it blocks my data curves. I want the curves to show over the filled rectangles. This is driving me nuts. Does anyone know how to put the filled rectangles in the background so they don't block data curves? Thanks.

Comment: I now have an alternative approach, so this issue is not critical for me anymore, but it would still be nice to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no option in the xmgrace graphical interface that allows you to modify the z order of drawing objects such as boxes:

[image]

I also saved the graph as an .agr file and viewed it in a text editor. There doesn't seem to be any flag within the file format to modify z position, either.
Same story if you save a parameter file and check it in a text editor.

So it looks like it is really **not possible** in xmgrace.

One workaround would be to print to a postscript, EPS or SVG file and open it inside a vector graphics program such as Inkscape (results vary, you might need to experiment with filetypes to see which works best). Then you can easily alter the z order of objects.